# Show (if possible without simplifying) that $f(x) =\sum_{i=1}^n \prod_{j \ne i} \frac{x-a_j}{a_i-a_j}=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Let $n>1$. Could you please show without any simplification?
It perhaps has an analytical method.
$$\begin{align}
\frac{(x − a_2)(x − a_3)\cdots(x − a_n)}{(a_1 − a_2)(a_1 − a_3)\cdots(a_1 − a_n)}  &+  \frac{(x − a_1)(x − a_3)\cdots(x − a_n)}{(a_2 − a_1)(a_2 − a_3)\cdots(a_2 − a_n)} \\[6pt]
&+ \cdots \\[6pt]
&+\frac{(x − a_1)(x − a_2)\cdots(x − a_{n-1})}{(a_n − a_2)(a_n − a_3)\cdots(a_n − a_{n-1})} \\[6pt]
&= 1
\end{align}$$

Comment: It is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ and it is equal to $1$ at the $n>n-1$ points $x=a_1,a_2,...,a_n$. See also [Lagrange interpolation polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

Comment: Oh! I have not done that. Thanks. So, does a polynomial having n roots and degree n-1 always equal 0?

Comment: Yes, as long as products of non-zero coefficients don't result in zero, which is the case for real or complex coefficients.

Comment: Understood. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the degree $n-1$ polynomial$$f(x) =\sum_{i=1}^n \prod_{j \ne i} \frac{x-a_j}{a_i-a_j}$$

We ahve $$f(a_k)=\prod_{j \ne k}\frac{a_k - a_j}{a_k-a_j}+\sum_{i=1\\i \ne k}^n \prod_{j \ne i} \frac{a_k-a_j}{a_i-a_j}=1+0=1$$

The degree $n-1$ polynomial takes the value $1$ at $n$ distinct values, hence it is the constant function $1$.

Note that $$\sum_{i=1\\i \ne k}^n \prod_{j \ne i} \frac{a_k-a_j}{a_i-a_j}=0$$ since one of the $j$ will take value $k$.